# django rest framework use RequestsClient with pytest

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

```
from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient

@pytest.mark.django_db()
def test(api_client):
    client = RequestsClient()
    response = client.get('http://www.google.com')
    print(response)
```

response always show 404

maybe RequestsClient should use with LiveServerTestCase.
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5803

Comment: Need more information. Your view that is being tested for example, error traceback.